# Replace a resource file in a WAR file in Gradle 3.5

Tags: gradle, war

I scanned the whole internet and found lots of answers, but neither worked for me properly.

I have the 2 files under

```
src/main/resources/
                  cluster.xml
                  a/
                    cluster.xml
```

In my war file I want to have the later.

So I tried:

```
war {
  from( 'src/main/resources' ){
    exclude 'cluster.xml'
    include 'a/cluster.xml'
    into 'WEB-INF/classes'
  }
}
```

and it put 2 copies of `a/cluster.xml` into `WEB-INF/classes/a` and a single `cluster.xml` into `WEB-INF/classes`.

I tried also using `webInf{}` with no success either.

UPDATE:

To make it a bit clear. I have a Grails 3.x / Springboot app. It has the default gradle task `bootRun` which runs the app in `development` mode w/o building the war-file. In this case the file `resources/cluster.xml` is picked from the classpath and the app works like charm.

For the `war` task I want to replace this single file, without breaking the `bootRun` task and keeping the whole config as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only modify the WAR, you'll need to access the `rootSpec` and perform some logic against the `cluster.xml` files.

```
war {
    rootSpec.includeEmptyDirs = false
    rootSpec.filesMatching('**/cluster.xml') { details ->
       if (details.sourcePath == "cluster.xml") {
           details.exclude()
       }
       if (details.sourcePath == "a/cluster.xml") {
           details.path = "WEB-INF/classes/cluster.xml"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: shall I put the `processResources` inside the `war`?

Comment: @injecteer Nope, it should be outside of `war { }`. This configures the `processResources` task, more info about it here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks

Comment: @injecteer Try out my updated answer. It only modifies the contents of the WAR as the files are being copied.

Comment: will try it out. Can you explain briefly what `rootSpec` means?

Comment: @injecteer Sure. The `war` task is a `Copy` task, which contains one or more `CopySpec`s that are each completely isolated from one another. `rootSpec` is the way in Gradle that you can alter the behavior of existing `CopySpec`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
sourceSets.main.resources.exclude '**/cluster.xml'

war {
  from( 'src/main/resources' ){
    exclude 'cluster.xml'
    include 'a/cluster.xml'
    into 'WEB-INF/classes'
  }
}
```

Comment: this would exclude `cluster.xml` from all tasks, which is the last thing I want

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on `exclude` which can be confusing, have you considered combining multiple `FileTrees` together? I much prefer adding two roots together rather than hacking excludes and moves within a single root

eg

```
- src/main/resources - Common stuff goes here
- src/a/resources/cluster.xml - Version A of cluster.xml
- src/b/resources/cluster.xml - Version B of cluster.xml
```

Once you've separated into different directories, you can add together the `FileTrees` that you need in a given situation. IMHO this is much better than using an exclude

Comment: I believe what you're suggesting is adding two additional SourceSets named `a` and `b`.

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case (when/where you want the `a` resources vs the `b` resources). You don't necessarily need to add `SourceSets` to use the `src/x/resources` convention as there's overhead involved (compile tasks etc). Who knows, you may go the "whole hog" and use my [java-flavours](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours) plugin

Comment: True, it just seemed like your suggestion aligned with the conventions of individual SourceSets.

Comment: Exactly, conventions are a powerful thing. If I saw 'a' and 'b' folders under the `src/main` directory I'd suspect these were flavour/variant specific files without even seeing the build file. `src/main/resources/a/cluster.xml` on the other hand is confusing

Comment: If it was only resources, I may choose initially not to use extra `SourceSets`. In future if there were additional `.java` files per flavour/variant it could easily change to `SourceSets` without changing the directory structure